# Set Bash Variable as Icon in osascript -e Display Dialog with icon

Tags: applescript, bash, icon

I have a bash script that utilizes some `osascript -e` code for a dialog. I want to use a custom icon in that dialog. However, I don't understand how to code it so it's completely portable so as to make it executable no matter where a user may put it in his file system.

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")/../../"
CONTENTS="$PWD"
export ICNSPATH="$CONTENTS/Resources/path/to/icon/Myicon.icns"
osascript -e 'tell application id "com.apple.systemuiserver"' -e 'display dialog "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} with icon '$ICNSPATH' as alias' -e 'end tell'
```

Currently the only way I can get it to work with a custom icon is by hard coding it and I don't think it is a good idea.

Solutions should be w/o add-ons and must work on Mac OSes 10.6 - 10.10.

Appreciate any help you can render.

Comment: How do you install/deploy the script? There seems to be some folder structure implied in your script.

Comment: @patrix It is used in a wine-wrapped application using the free, open source Wineskin application.

Answer (score 3):

What always will work is encoding the icon file with `base64 -b 64` (to keep the lines short enough), include it into your shell script as a here document and decode it on the fly.

To create a base64 encoded version of your icon file, run

```
base64 -b 64 -i path/to/icon/Myicon.icns > myicon.base64
```

(This you only need to do once).

Then open your shell script in your editor and *insert* `myicon.base64` (which might be rather big) in the correct spot

```
...
ICNSPATH=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/icon.$$.icns
base64 -D -o $ICNSPATH <<"END_OF_ICON"
** replace with content of myicon.base64 **
END_OF_ICON

osascript -e '... with icon '$ICNSPATH' as alias' # write full command here
rm -f $ICNSPATH
```

The final script will then look like the following

```
...
ICNSPATH=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/icon.$$.icns
base64 -D -o $ICNSPATH <<"END_OF_ICON"
aG93IHRvIGNvZGUgaXQgc28gaXQncyBjb21wbGV0ZWx5IHBvcnRhYmxlIHNvIGFz
...
eSBwdXQgaXQgaW4gaGlzIGZpbGUgc3lzdGVtLgoK
END_OF_ICON

osascript -e '... with icon '$ICNSPATH' as alias'
rm -f $ICNSPATH
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's way over my head, I don't have the first idea how to use it.

Comment: I've added some more details

Comment: You did help me with my thinking and logic, and I think you for that, but I found a better way accomplish my goal of using a custom icon in my script. Now I just copy the icon to /tmp and delete it when the script completes.

Comment: I was interrupted in above comment, should say "I thank you for that".